# How to Turn on Music (ipod library) on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, alarm

I already know how to keep play music at background in my app.

I don't want to know that.

I want this.

how to Automatically turn on ipot music in background & sleep mode at custom time.

it's thought impossible to me.

but that's possible. and no jail break.

i wanna know that.  please help me.

Comment: Do you want this programmatically.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following background task guide from the iOS docs

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

There are restrictions on what can be carried out in the background. Certain apps that support audio, location, and voip are allowed to run in background using the UIBackgroundModes key. With the audio background task, it will not be suspended until the audio session stops.

It seems that you don't want to initiate a session until a certain time. You could potentially look at beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: .

Also if you are looking for a timed alarm, you can always attach a different tone to a local notification.

As far as I am aware, there is no "out-of-the-box" way to do what your asking.